# Create new select when somebody click in the option

Tags: javascript

There is a select with a list of countries. Choosing a country it should create new select with a list of cities from this country.

```js
var selectCountries = document.getElementById("countries");

var options = selectCountries.options;

for( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ){

 options[i].addEventListener("click",funct )
}

function funct(){
 var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");

 var newCities = document.createElement("select");

 main.appendChild(newCities);

 var newOptions = document.createElement("option");

 newCities.appendChild(newOptions);


}
```

```html
<div id="main"> <select id="countries"> <option>France</option> <option>Germany</option> </select> </div>
```

Comment: <div id="main">

<select id="countries">
  <option>France</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
</select>

</div>

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: create one `<select id="cities">` then hide it, then we don't need to care about whether `<select id="cities">` exists when selecting one country.

For DOM, you need to loop options under `<select id="countries">` to check which option is selected. so I created one function=**getSelectedValue**

And I created one `var citiesConfigs` to save all cities, then when selecting one city, pull out all cities under the selected county.

Finally, in function=**funct**,

1. get selected option for `<select id="countries">`
2. get all cities under the selected country, loop them to create `<option>` then append to `<select id="cities">`
3. finally, show up `<select id="cities">`

```js
var selectCountries = document.getElementById("countries");

var options = selectCountries.options;

for( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ){

 options[i].addEventListener("click",funct )
}

var citiesConfigs = {'france': ['CityA', 'CityB'], 'germany':['CityC','CityD']}

function getSelectedValue(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
}

function funct(){
 var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");

 var selectedCity = document.getElementById("cities")
  selectedCity.innerHTML = ''
  citiesConfigs[getSelectedValue('countries')].forEach(function(city){
    let newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = city
    newOption.text = city
    selectedCity.appendChild(newOption);
  })
  selectedCity.style.display = ''
}
```

```html
<div id="main"> <select id="countries"> <option value="france">France</option> <option value="germany">Germany</option> </select>
<select id="cities" style="display:none"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: i need only javascript)